# Muiltple Modal UIViewControllers | Dismiss Top Modal UIViewController Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

My `UIViewController` stack looks as follows:

```
+------ UIViewController_C (presented)
+---- UIViewController_B (presented)
+-- UIViewController_A (pushed)
```

When I call `-dismissViewController:animated` on `UIViewController_C`,  `UINavigationController` dismisses **both** `UIViewController_C` and `UIViewController_B` together, as per the docs with animation on `_C`, and none on `_B`.

What is the most compliant way to dismiss `_C` **only**?

Comment: Please share your code. In ordinary situation it should work.

Comment: - found the solution; will add after 8 hours as I am unable to write it up due to my poor rep.

Comment: Thank you @malex - super kind; I was broadly thinking along the same lines as you and will share that as soon as I am able (T-4hrs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as below

after pushing to UIViewController_A present UIViewController_B as below code.

```
UIViewController_B *bbp=[[UIViewController_B alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController_B" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
passcodeNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
[passcodeNavigationController release];
```

now from UIViewController_B try to present in UIViewController_C as below code.

```
    UIViewController_C *bbp=[[UIViewController_C alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController_C" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
passcodeNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
[passcodeNavigationController release];
```

last and final thing on every back button of view controller write below line of code.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if you want more help than comment bellow.

Answer (score 0):

**One Solution:**

`UIViewControllers` presented modally are not necessarily `deallocated` on -`dismissViewController:animated`.

This means that by passing a reference to `UIViewController_A` through `_B` to `_C`, you can call `-presentViewController:animated` and `-dismissViewController:animated` for the respective `UIViewControllers` via `UIViewController_A`.

**Code:**

**1. UIViewController_B**

```
- (void) showUIViewController_C {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
        UIViewController_C *controller_C = [[UIViewController_C alloc] init];
        controller_C.parentController = self;
        [self.parentController controller_C animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

**2. UIViewController_C**

```
- (void) dismissUIViewController_C {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
        [self.parentController.parentController presentViewController:self.parentController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Where I am using `*parentController` as the naming convention for whatever class your previous `UIViewController` on the stack may be.

It dips back to `UIViewController_A` briefly because I am calling `-dismiss` and `-present` in the completion block, though that actually looks rather fun.